# Best practices for preventing Denial of Service via node.js uncaught Exceptions

Tags: node.js

So I have recently implemented a pattern similar to that suggested by node.js's domain documentation (http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors) to gracefully crash the server if an uncaught exception happens.

However it's easily apparent that it is possible to create a denial of service by rapidly triggering errors, since it takes a significant amount of time to start a new process.

Is there any recommended best practices for mitigating this?

Comment: I can cause the same DoS by rapidly firing a bunch of valid http requests. You're putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: One might ask why you accept inputs that can cause exceptions in the first place?  Aren't you missing some validity checks on the data?

Answer (score 2):

- log your uncaught exceptions
- read the logs
- take the time to understand, reproduce, and fix the bugs
- keep deploying new versions of your app where uncaught exceptions are increasingly rare
- use the cluster module and load balancers for fault tolerance
- consider network level DoS protection if you really need it
- Have a web server configuration handy where for the easy case of a particular URL crashes your app, you can have your web server quickly start filtering those requests so they never reach your application server. This could be done with an nginx location block that just sends a fail whale type response.

  - Realize that this only helps some cases. In complex cases where a specially-crafted POST message body crashes your app and turning off that entire URL will block legitimate user access, you'll need to respond by deploying better code.

Comment: I'm specifically concerned about mitigating the case where we have some URI causing uncaught exceptions, which maliciously or not is hit very rapidly causing a whole cluster or multiple nodes to have to restart their processes, taking the app offline.

Even if we catch and hotfix the exception, we don't want to have 15-20 minutes of downtime while we're doing a fire drill to patch it.

Comment: Answer updated with one option that might help in some cases.